# Entanglement in laser beams

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Recent experiments in entanglement of two laser beams using OPOs indicates higher level (photon group instead of pair) of entanglement. When a higher ensemble of photons are entangled there is no clarity as to how entanglement proceeds. Let us use V and H polarization of two beams to define the two quantum states of the system. If I split of the two beams and observe polarization of the split beam will it or will it not affect the polarization of conjugate beam?
Here is a [[link]](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2008/jul/29/laser-beams-are-entangled-in-space) of an artice which demonstrates spatial entanglement of two laser beams.

Comment: Can you add a proper citation, please? It's kind of hard to entangle minds over the internet sufficiently to know which paper you are thinking about. Entanglement is an effect on quantum states in general. While it may be the easiest to implement on single particle pairs, there is no limit to how "large" an entangled quantum state can be. In the limit this allows for (nearly) continuous quantum variables which, in this case, are implemented with many photons. That's how I would interpret it without any further reference.

Comment: This could use a lot more detail. What *exactly* is the experimental setup here? What does "higher level of entanglement mean"? Higher than *what*? What is the measure of "level of entanglement"?

Comment: Thanks for the link... it's kind of cute. I am trying to understand the Science paper they wrote in detail. It seems to boil down to what I thought it was and it's a lot less exciting in the actual paper than in the press release, but it's an interesting demonstration of entanglement, nonetheless.

Comment: I want to gain insight regarding behavior of photons inside the beam. For example if i split the one beam into two and change polarization of one half of the beam what would be the effect on second beam? Will half the beam get effected or the whole beam?

Comment: Not sure that this article talk about the common quantum entanglement ...

Comment: Because of the beam splitter in the joint pat of the beams, you cannot know from which beam each photon originated ... this is the source of the entanglement.  There is no limit in theory as to the number of particles which can be mutually entangled.

Comment: there is no limit i can understand that but how does entanglement works where multiple entities are involved. Lets take an example - there are four photons in one beam and four others in another. Horizontal and Vertical polarization of a beam is taken as definition of vector state of the beam. When the two beams are entangled how does one define an entangled quantum state? Just like in a pair of photon? What if one photon in one beam accidentally changes its polarization. How will it effect the other beam? I am just perplexed at how is entanglement proceeding at photon level.

Comment: Consider any two independent particle states, $|1> and |2>$. If they are independent then measuring one has no influence on the other.  We can safely write the state of the pair as a tensor product, $|1>|2>$, which is an element of the Hilbert space which is the tensor product space of the two independent Hilbert spaces.  If it is not possible to write the state in this fashion, it is called an entangled state - and there will be aspects of the pair which are no longer independent.  Not knowing the origin of the particles coming out of a beam splitter is one way to achieve this!

Comment: It has been marked as closed but I now know that pure quantum states for such a quantum system does not exist.